# Zend_Controller tries to execute my stylesheets as controller

Tags: zend-framework, controller, stylesheet, zend-controller

I initialize my placeholders for my global layout within the *Bootstrap.php* as described [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.view.placeholders.standard.html).

```
public function _initPlaceholders()
{
    $this->bootstrap('View');
    $view = $this->getResource('View');

    $view->doctype('XHTML11');

    $view->headTitle('Foo Bar Title')
         ->setSeparator(' :: ');

    $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv(
        'content-type',
        'application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8'
    );

    $view->headMeta()->appendName('robots', 'index,follow');

    $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/styles.css', 'screen')
                     ->appendStylesheet('/styles/print.css', 'print');
}
```

The rendered HTML looks correct.

```
<title>Foo Bar Title</title>
<link href="/styles/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/styles/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
```

But the CSS doesn't get loaded correctly because Zend_Controller thinks it's a controller or something. When I try to open the CSS files the following error occurs:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception'
>   with message 'Invalid controller
>   specified (error)'

Any hints?

**[update]**

Ok, just added the following line to my .htaccess file and all works as expected now...

> RewriteRule
>   !.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|swf|htm)$
>   index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical Zend project layout looks something like this:

```
.
|-- application
|   |-- Bootstrap.php
|   |-- configs
|   |-- controllers
|   |-- forms
|   |-- layouts
|   |-- models
|   `-- views
|-- library
`-- public
    |-- images
    |   `-- favicon.ico
    |-- index.php
    |-- js
    |   `-- scripts.js
    `-- styles
        `-- style.css
```

Does yours look similar?  Specifically, do you have CSS and JavaScript files somewhere under the public folder (and not the application folder)?  If so, can you review file permissions?

Also, I recommend reviewing file permissions.  If the CSS files aren't readable by the Apache process, then Apache won't be able to serve them.

Comment: My directory layout ist "by the book" due to the usage of Zend_Tool. It were wrong file permissions. :-/ *thx*