# Invalid controller specified (css) in Zend framework

Tags: php, css, zend-framework

I am trying to apply css in the Zend Framework. My css file is in `public/css/layout.css`. First of all I added the following code lines in `bootstrap.php`:

```
protected function _initPlaceholders()
 {
   $this->bootstrap('View');
   $view = $this->getResource('View');
   $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

   // Set the initial title and separator:
   $view->headTitle('My Site')
        ->setSeparator(' :: ');

   // Set the initial stylesheet:
   $view->headLink()->prependStylesheet('../../css/layout.css');
 }
```

Which simply specifies the title and stylesheet to be used. Then in `layout.phtml` I add the following code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<?php
echo $this->headTitle();
echo $this->headScript();
// add a link to the site style sheet
echo '';
echo $this->headLink();

?>
</head>
```

Which simply adds link of the stylesheet specified in `bootstrap.php`.

But when I run the project then I am getting the form without css. Why is this? When I check the css with Firebug in a Mozilla browser it says:

```
<h3>Exception information:</h3>
<p>
<b>Message:</b> Invalid controller specified (css) </p>
<h3>Stack trace:</h3>
<h3>Request Parameters:</h3>
<pre>array (
   'controller' =&gt; 'css',
   'action' =&gt; 'layout.css',
   'module' =&gt; 'default',
 ) </pre>
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Accept answers to your previous questions and you might get some help in return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$view->headLink()->prependStylesheet('/css/layout.css');
```

this should help.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have this code on your /public/.htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

If you don't have the first 4 lines, this file will redirect your request of "css/layout.css" to index.php and then, Zend will interpret it as a link for a controller -> action.

If you have this file, make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled on your server.

And you sould put your link as "akond" said.

Good luck =)

Comment: .htaccess file contains the above lines and rewrite module is enabled on server also as in httpd.conf I have uncommented the line LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
But still same problem.

Comment: Can you access the css file with a direct link? Example: http://www.mydomain.com/css/layout.css? Or does it returns the same thing that firebug reports?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

> [Zend_Controller tries to execute my stylesheets as controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6346095/2524250)
>
> [update]
>
> Ok, just added the following line to my .htaccess file and all works as expected now...
>
> `RewriteRule !.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|swf|htm)$ index.php`

but then I found this one:

http://devzone.zend.com/1651/managing-css-and-javascript-files-within-a-zend-framework-app/